# useEffect addEventListener подписывается на одно и то же событие каждое обновление useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

`KeyDownCallback` - получено из props. `Window` каждый раз при обновление зависимостей `useEffect` подписывается на событие *keydown* с разными `handleKeyDown` (где различается `isFocus`). Таким образом `keyDownCallback` вызывается столько раз, сколько `window` подписалось на событие. Как исправить, чтобы `window` не подписывалось несколько раз, но при этом `handleKeyDown` использовало актуальное значение `isFocus`?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = e => {
      if (e.code === "KeyE" || (isFocus && e.code === "Enter")) {
        if (keyDownCallback) keyDownCallback();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);

    return () => window.removeEventListener(onkeydown, handleKeyDown);
  }, [isFocus, keyDownCallback]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже на то что сдесь упустили - return () => window.removeEventListener(onkeydown, handleKeyDown);

onkeydown должен быть строкой и не onkeydown а keydown

тоесть так:

```
return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
```

Comment: Да, верно. Глупая невнимательность. Спасибо